# How can I calculate confidence intervals for epsilon-squared (Effect size for Kruskal-Wallis test) in R?

Tags: r, effect-size, kruskal-wallis-test

I'd like to calculate the confidence intervals for the epsilon-squared effect size statistic in R. Here is the code I'm using to calculate the epsilon-squared value:

```
#set up two vectors, a numerical vector and a factor vector (grouping variable)
x=c(3,2,4,7,4,6,9,2,3,4,1,0,8,6,9,5,3,3,6,7,8,2,8,9)
y=as.factor(c(rep("cond1",12),rep("cond2",12)))

#run kruskal-wallis test
kruskal.test(x~y)
library(rcompanion)
df=data.frame(x,y)

#calculate epsilon squared
epsilonSquared(x = df$x, 
       g = df$y)
```

This gives me my effect size. But the function only outputs a single figure. How can I calculate the confidence intervals of the effect size, please?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the help file via `?epsilonSquared`? You can simply set the corresponding argument in the function to be true (default is `FALSE`):

```
epsilonSquared(x = df$x, g = df$y, ci = TRUE, conf = 0.95)
```

This returns a 95% bootstrapped confidence interval. If you don't set a seed, it will be slightly different each time (since it's bootstrapped).

Comment: Thank you! But even using conf=xx, only a single value is returned - no values for the upper/lower limit of the confidence intervals. Do you know if there is any way I can access those values?

Comment: Update: I reinstalled the package and now this returns the CI values as well - thank you so much!!

Comment: you're welcome! If you are familiar with the technical aspects of bootstrap you can also specify the type of bootstrap via the argument `type`. For the CIs, `epsilonSquared` makes use of `boot.ci` if you want more details. However, the default will work fine for most applications.